# Dropdown to select from multiple forms

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

JS

```
$('p select[name=Membership_Selection]').change(function(e){
  if ($('p select[name=Membership_Selection]').val() == 'Z'){
    $('#Z').show();
  }else{
    $('#Z').hide();
  }
});



$('p select[name=Membership_Selection]').change(function(e){
  if ($('p select[name=Membership_Selection]').val() == 'A_A''){
    $('#A_A').show();
  }else{
    $('#A_A'').hide();
  }
});


$('p select[name=Membership_Selection]').change(function(e){
  if ($('p select[name=Membership_Selection]').val() == 'B_B'){
    $('#B_B').show();
  }else{
    $('#B_B').hide();
  }
});



$('p select[name=Membership_Selection]').change(function(e){
  if ($('p select[name=Membership_Selection]').val() == 'C_C'){
    $('#C_C').show();
  }else{
    $('#C_C').hide();
  }
});



$('p select[name=Membership_Selection]').change(function(e){
  if ($('p select[name=Membership_Selection]').val() == 'D_D'){
    $('#D_D').show();
  }else{
    $('#D_D').hide();
  }
});



$('p select[name=Membership_Selection]').change(function(e){
  if ($('p select[name=Membership_Selection]').val() == 'E_E'){
    $('#E_E').show();
  }else{
    $('#E_E').hide();
  }
});



$('p select[name=Membership_Selection]').change(function(e){
  if ($('p select[name=Membership_Selection]').val() == 'F_F'){
    $('#F_F').show();
  }else{
    $('#F_F').hide();
  }
});



$('p select[name=Membership_Selection]').change(function(e){
  if ($('p select[name=Membership_Selection]').val() == 'G_G'){
    $('#G_G').show();
  }else{
    $('#G_G').hide();
  }
});



$('p select[name=Membership_Selection]').change(function(e){
  if ($('p select[name=Membership_Selection]').val() == 'H_H'){
    $('#H_H').show();
  }else{
    $('#H_H').hide();
  }
});
```

CSS

```css
/*------------------------------------*\
    Members Dropdown
\*------------------------------------*/

#A_A{display:none;}
#B_B{display:none;}
#C_C{display:none;}
#D_D{display:none;}
#E_E{display:none;}
#F_F{display:none;}
#G_G{display:none;}
#H_H{display:none;}
```

HTML

```
        <div id="membership" align="right">         


            <p> <font size="2"><center><b>Become a Member</b></p></font></center>

                    <table>
                    <tbody><tr><td>
                <p> <center> <font size="2">Alphabet Soup Membership Type</font></center></td></tr><tr><td>

<p><center>
<select name ="Membership_Selection" required>
<option value="Z">-- Select an Option --</option>
<option value="A_A">a a $5 year</option>
<option value="B_B">b b $10 year</option>
<option value="C_C">c c : $15 year</option>
<option value="D_D">d d $20 year</option>
<option value="E_E">e e $25 year</option>
<option value="F_F">f f : $30 year</option>
<option value="G_G">g g : $35 year</option>
<option value="H_H">h h : $40 year</option>
</select></center></p>



<center>
<form id="Z" target="paypal" action="" method="post">
<input class="memsubbut" value="Subscribe" type="submit"  border="0" name="submit" alt="PayPal"></center>
</form>

<center>
<form id="A_A" target="paypal" action="https://www.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr" method="post">
<input type="hidden" name="cmd" value="_xclick-subscriptions">
<input type="hidden" name="business" value="me@mysite.com">
<input type="hidden" name="item_name" value="Alpha Member - AA">
<input type="hidden" name="item_number" value="AA">
<input type="hidden" name="no_shipping" value="1">
<input type="hidden" name="no_note" value="1">
<input type="hidden" name="currency_code" value="USD">
<input type="hidden" name="a3" value="5">
<input type="hidden" name="p3" value="1">
<input type="hidden" name="t3" value="Y">
<input type="hidden" name="src" value="1">
<input type="hidden" name="sra" value="1">
<input type="hidden" name="return" value="https://example.com/thanks.php">
<input type="hidden" name="notify_url" value="http://example.com/pay_paypal/paypal.php">
<input class="memsubbut" value="Subscribe" type="submit"  border="0" name="submit" alt="PayPal">
</form></center>


<center>
<form id="B_B" target="paypal" action="https://www.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr" method="post">
<input type="hidden" name="cmd" value="_xclick-subscriptions">
<input type="hidden" name="business" value="me@mysite.com">
<input type="hidden" name="item_name" value="Alpha Member - BB">
<input type="hidden" name="item_number" value="BB">
<input type="hidden" name="no_shipping" value="1">
<input type="hidden" name="no_note" value="1">
<input type="hidden" name="currency_code" value="USD">
<input type="hidden" name="a3" value="10">
<input type="hidden" name="p3" value="1">
<input type="hidden" name="t3" value="Y">
<input type="hidden" name="src" value="1">
<input type="hidden" name="sra" value="1">
<input type="hidden" name="return" value="https://example.com/thanks.php">
<input type="hidden" name="notify_url" value="https://example.com/pay_paypal/paypal.php">
<input class="memsubbut" value="Subscribe" type="submit"  border="0" name="submit" alt="PayPal">
</form></center>

<center>
<form id="C_C" target="paypal" action="https://www.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr" method="post">
<input type="hidden" name="cmd" value="_xclick-subscriptions">
<input type="hidden" name="business" value="me@mysite.com">
<input type="hidden" name="item_name" value="Alpha Member - CC">
<input type="hidden" name="item_number" value="CC">
<input type="hidden" name="no_shipping" value="1">
<input type="hidden" name="no_note" value="1">
<input type="hidden" name="currency_code" value="USD">
<input type="hidden" name="a3" value="15">
<input type="hidden" name="p3" value="1">
<input type="hidden" name="t3" value="Y">
<input type="hidden" name="src" value="1">
<input type="hidden" name="sra" value="1">
<input type="hidden" name="return" value="https://example.com/thanks.php>
<input type="hidden" name="notify_url" value="https://example.com/pay_paypal/paypal.php">
<input class="memsubbut" value="Subscribe" type="submit"  border="0" name="submit" alt="PayPal">
</form></center>

<center>
<form id="D_D" target="paypal" action="https://www.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr" method="post">
<input type="hidden" name="cmd" value="_xclick-subscriptions">
<input type="hidden" name="business" value="me@mysite.com">
<input type="hidden" name="item_name" value="Alpha Member - DD">
<input type="hidden" name="item_number" value="DD">
<input type="hidden" name="no_shipping" value="1">
<input type="hidden" name="no_note" value="1">
<input type="hidden" name="currency_code" value="USD">
<input type="hidden" name="a3" value="20">
<input type="hidden" name="p3" value="1">
<input type="hidden" name="t3" value="Y">
<input type="hidden" name="src" value="1">
<input type="hidden" name="sra" value="1">
<input type="hidden" name="return" value="https://example.com/thanks.php">
<input type="hidden" name="notify_url" value="https://example.com/pay_paypal/paypal.php">
<input class="memsubbut" value="Subscribe" type="submit"  border="0" name="submit" alt="PayPal">
</form></center>

<center>
<form id="E_E" target="paypal" action="https://www.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr" method="post">
<input type="hidden" name="cmd" value="_xclick-subscriptions">
<input type="hidden" name="business" value="me@mysite.com">
<input type="hidden" name="item_name" value="Alpha Member - EE">
<input type="hidden" name="item_number" value="EE">
<input type="hidden" name="no_shipping" value="1">
<input type="hidden" name="no_note" value="1">
<input type="hidden" name="currency_code" value="USD">
<input type="hidden" name="a3" value="25">
<input type="hidden" name="p3" value="1">
<input type="hidden" name="t3" value="Y">
<input type="hidden" name="src" value="1">
<input type="hidden" name="sra" value="1">
<input type="hidden" name="return" value="https://example.com/thanks.php">
<input type="hidden" name="notify_url" value="https://example.com/pay_paypal/paypal.php">
<input class="memsubbut" value="Subscribe" type="submit"  border="0" name="submit" alt="PayPal">
</form></center>

<center>
<form id="F_F" target="paypal" action="https://www.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr" method="post">
<input type="hidden" name="cmd" value="_xclick-subscriptions">
<input type="hidden" name="business" value="me@mysite.com">
<input type="hidden" name="item_name" value="Alpha Member - FF">
<input type="hidden" name="item_number" value="FF">
<input type="hidden" name="no_shipping" value="1">
<input type="hidden" name="no_note" value="1">
<input type="hidden" name="currency_code" value="USD">
<input type="hidden" name="a3" value="30">
<input type="hidden" name="p3" value="1">
<input type="hidden" name="t3" value="Y">
<input type="hidden" name="src" value="1">
<input type="hidden" name="sra" value="1">
<input type="hidden" name="return" value="https://example.com/thanks.php">
<input type="hidden" name="notify_url" value="https://example.com/pay_paypal/paypal.php">
<input class="memsubbut" value="Subscribe" type="submit"  border="0" name="submit" alt="PayPal">
</form></center>

<center>
<form id="G_G" target="paypal" action="https://www.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr" method="post">
<input type="hidden" name="cmd" value="_xclick-subscriptions">
<input type="hidden" name="business" value="me@mysite.com">
<input type="hidden" name="item_name" value="Alpha Member - GG">
<input type="hidden" name="item_number" value="GG">
<input type="hidden" name="no_shipping" value="1">
<input type="hidden" name="no_note" value="1">
<input type="hidden" name="currency_code" value="USD">
<input type="hidden" name="a3" value="35">
<input type="hidden" name="p3" value="1">
<input type="hidden" name="t3" value="Y">
<input type="hidden" name="src" value="1">
<input type="hidden" name="sra" value="1">
<input type="hidden" name="return" value="https://example.com/thanks.php">
<input type="hidden" name="notify_url" value="https://example.com/pay_paypal/paypal.php">
<input class="memsubbut" value="Subscribe" type="submit"  border="0" name="submit" alt="PayPal">
</form></center>

<center>
<form id="H_H" target="paypal" action="https://www.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr" method="post">
<input type="hidden" name="cmd" value="_xclick-subscriptions">
<input type="hidden" name="business" value="me@mysite.com">
<input type="hidden" name="item_name" value="Alpha Member - HH">
<input type="hidden" name="item_number" value="HH">
<input type="hidden" name="no_shipping" value="1">
<input type="hidden" name="no_note" value="1">
<input type="hidden" name="currency_code" value="USD">
<input type="hidden" name="a3" value="40">
<input type="hidden" name="p3" value="1">
<input type="hidden" name="t3" value="Y">
<input type="hidden" name="src" value="1">
<input type="hidden" name="sra" value="1">
<input type="hidden" name="return" value="https://example.com/thanks.php">
<input type="hidden" name="notify_url" value="https://example.com/pay_paypal/paypal.php">
<input class="memsubbut" value="Subscribe" type="submit"  border="0" name="submit" alt="PayPal">
</form></center>
                    </td></tr>
                    </tbody>
                    </table>




            </div><!-- #membership -->
```

What am I missing? I thought is was working in sandbox, but I guess didn't look closely.

Essentially, I hid all forms (buttons) in CSS. I then us JS to show them, but only one at a time. 
Then HTML for the dropdown select. Is the problem in the JS, selecting the form?
Thanks in advance!

Comment: Your JS contains a syntax error -  a double closing quote. Your code could also be *massively* simplified by following DRY principles.

Comment: Wow, lot's of repeat code here that could be cleared /cleaned up.

Comment: Ok, please help. I'm not a formally trained (lol - I guess you can tell). :-) This is all I need to be up and running. What can I do to straighten it out?

Comment: you have a lot of stuff wrong with that code. You might want to start with the basics. I'm building a Fiddle for you, but I don't think I'll have time to finish

Comment: I'm aware it's no good. This is why I'm pleading for help. It's clear you know how to do what I need. Why are you not helping? Please don't just bash it and put -1. I'm not trying to post for others. I'm asking for help, please. Thank you cr0ss.

Comment: You can start by keeping it simple: do it for 2 items on the dropdownlist, and then extend. It's very hard to see and debug your code from where I'm standing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This **[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/MgNLW/)** BEGINS to help you with your problem.

```
$(document).ready(function () {

    $('select[name=Membership_Selection]').change(function (e) {
        switch ($(this).val()) {
            case "A":
                hideAllExcept($("#A"));
                break;
            case "B":
                hideAllExcept($("#B"));
                break;
            case "C":
                hideAllExcept($("#C"));
               break;
           default:
               // do something defaultly
       }
   });
});

function hideAllExcept(toShow) {
    toShow.show();
    $("#membership").find('div').each(function () {               
        if ($(this).attr('id') != toShow.attr('id')) {
            $(this).hide();
        }
    });
}
```

I had to remove A LOT of code so I could understand. Now you just need to paste some stuff in there and get to work.

Some hints:

- 1) Don't use **center** tag, like, ever;
- 2) Careful with some typos, like double single quotes when you only meant one. Also, 'a'
  is different from 'a ', so be extra careful;
- 3) First, try to build the whole HTML BEFORE using styles (like the **font** tag, ew),
  and style everything using CSS;
- 4) Don't use **table** as mean of styling;
- 5) Refator your code before continuing doing anything else, please.

This is **NOT** the entire answer you need, but it was what I was able to do.

Comment: Thanks cr0ss. That got me squared away! Sorry for the delay... just wanted to get it complete, to make sure I was good. Obviously new here. Looked for a way to send you a private message, but didn't see a way. Was going to give you member access (login details) to my site, to thank you for your help. :-) Thanks so much. If you can tell me a way to do so privately, I'd be happy to do so. Thanks again!

Comment: @user3670268 Glad to help! Hope everything is working fine now :)